# C programming get numbers next to text from text

Tags: c, text, char, getchar

I am writing a program that needs to get money values from text, when ever there is "rsd" next to it like : `"20rsd,100rsd,500rsd.."` or

```
John has 20rsd, Danny has 30rsd. Bill gave 40rsd.
```

Result :  `90`

I tried something but don't know how to do it. BTW, this is from college test I had.

```
int main()
{
char c,d,f;
int price;
FILE *in;
char rsd[] = {'r','s','d'}; 

in = fopen("moneytext.txt","r");

while(!feof(in))
{
    c = fgetc(in);
    if(c=='r')
    {
        d = fgetc(in);
        if(d == 's')
        {
            f = fgetc(in);
            if(f == 'd')
                printf("%c%c%c",c,d,f); //Prints rsd
        }
    }
}
//printf("%c",fgetc(in));
}
```

Textfile is something like this:

```
20.10.2017. John gave me 10rsd and Lisa gave me 30rsd, Danny gave me 50rsd, Nicholas donated 10rsd.
```

Comment: Can you edit your post on show us the content of your textfile?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's SO is not for solving college test

Comment: [Little example using scanf](http://ideone.com/sFkBSb#view_edit_box)...in your case should `fscanf`

Comment: Hint: your approach is completely wrong.

Comment: @peko it's not solving college test it's something similar to what we had on test, i came to stop. I don't know how to do it. So i came here seeking for help.

Answer (score 1):

For each input line, you may recursively find sub-string "rsd", once find one:

1. reversely find digit to get price
2. continue find "rsd" after current "rsd"+3

It may looks like:

```
while(fgets(buf, size, fd) != NULL)
{
    char *start = buf;
    /* search for rsd */
    while(start = strstr(start, "rsd"))
    {
        p = start;

        /* reverse find the start of price */
        while(p > buf && IS_DIGIT(*(p-1)))
        {                
            p--;
        }
        if(p < start)
        {
            while(p < start)
            {
                price = price * 10 + *p - '0';
            }
            /** do something about price here */
        }
        start += 3;
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't see any recursion here. You are probably mixing up "recursion" and "repetition".

Answer (score 0):

Code can loop looking for 1 of N conditions

1. A digit was found: Accumulate the integer value `price`.
2. A single character match in the suffix pattern was found: Advance to the next character.  If the entire pattern was found, add the `price`.
3. Neither.  Reset pattern and price.
4. Continue until `EOF` found.

---

```
int main() {
  // Use a string to include \0 to denote when to stop match
  const char *rsd = "rsd";

  FILE *out = fopen("moneytext.txt", "w");
  fputs("123 John has 20rsd, Danny456 has 30rsd. Bill789 gave 40rsd", out);
  fclose(out);

  FILE *in = fopen("moneytext.txt", "r");
  if (in) {
    // fgetc() return an int, typically 1 of 257 different values, char is insufficient.
    int c;
    int sum = 0;
    int price = 0;
    const char *pattern = rsd;
    while ((c = fgetc(in)) != EOF) {
      if (isdigit(c)) {
        price = price * 10 + c - '0';
        pattern = rsd;
      } else if (c == (unsigned char) *pattern) {
        pattern++;
        if (*pattern == '\0') {
          pattern = rsd;
          sum += price;
          price = 0;
        }
      } else {
        pattern = rsd;
        price = 0;
      }
    }
    fclose(in);
    printf("Sum:%d\n", sum);
  }
}
```

Output

```
Sum:90
```

Additional code is needed to handle negative numbers, detect `int` overflow, `FILE` errors, etc.